# Learning from C Primer. Expected Expression Error Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, syntax

I am learning C++ from the C primer. 
I am stuck on the last part of this question (1.6(p. 25))

> Exercises Section 2.6.2
>   Exercise 2.41: Use your Sales_data class to rewrite the exercises in § 1.5.1 (p. 22), § 1.5.2 >(p. 24), and § 1.6 (p. 25). For now, you should define your Sales_data class in the same file >as your main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Sales_data 
{
    std::string Book_Name;
    unsigned Units_Sold = 0;
    double Revenue = 0.0;
};

int main()
{
    double price;
    Sales_data total;  // variable to hold data for the next transaction // read the first transaction and ensure that there are data to process
    if (std::cin >> total.Book_Name >> total.Units_Sold >> price) 
    {
        total.Revenue = total.Units_Sold * price;
        Sales_data trans; // variable to hold the running sum // read and process the remaining transactions
        while (std::cin >> trans.Book_Name >> trans.Units_Sold >> price) 
        {
            trans.Revenue = trans.Units_Sold*price;
            // if we're still processing the same book
            if (total.Book_Name == trans.Book_Name)
            {
                total.Units_Sold += trans.Units_Sold; // update the running 
                total.Revenue += trans.Revenue; // update the running 
            }
            else 
            {
            std::cout << total.Book_Name << total.Units_Sold << total.Revenue;
            **￼￼total.Book_Name = trans.Book_Name;**
            total.Units_Sold = trans.Units_Sold;
            **￼￼total.Revenue = trans.Revenue;**
            }
            ￼**std::cout << total.Book_Name << total.Units_Sold << price << std::endl;** //print the last transaction 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // no input! warn the user
        std::cerr << "No data?!" << std::endl; 
        return -1; // indicate failure
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Where there are ** Xcode keeps telling me expected expression.. I have no clue what is wrong please help...

Comment: Did you copy and paste code from an ebook version because the code above has odd characters in it.

Comment: I copied and then edited the code myself..
I think that might have been the problem as after I deleted some spaces and pressed enter and backspace a couple of times near the problem area the expected expression errors disappeared... Weird.. Thanks Shafik

My problem is SOLVED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment you introduced some odd characters when you copied some code from the ebook. When I copied and compiled the program with `gcc` I received errors like the following(*[live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dbd05509b3ff87d)*):

```
error: stray ‘\357’ in program
```

`\357` is an octal escape sequence. When those characters are removed the program compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks! Now that i know why I will make sure it doesnt happen again! :D

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Shafik Yaghmours answer.

Some code I copied needed for me to retype the word **float**!

> const ﬂoat TEMPCOMP = ( 200 + (dT2 * (c6+100) >> 11) ) / 10;

I cant copy and paste to show how it looks..cause both lines (before and after)
look the same when I past it here.

But in the editor(Arduino)...you can clearly see a difference.
The f and l of float are touching!

Actually it was a Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FL' (U+FB02)
[FileFormat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb02/index.htm)